# Setting margins in a Page Template file for WordPress -- html and css?

Tags: margins

I'm creating a Page Template for a WordPress site.

In the file newpagetemplate.php I currently have this code, and this code only:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
 <title>Copywriting for Serious Marketers</title>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
 <meta name="keywords" content="copywriting, sales writing, marketing" />
 <meta name="copyright" content="Copyright Richard Clunan. All rights reserved." />
 <meta name="description" content="Advice on copywriting and marketing." />
 <meta name="revisit-after" content="7 days" />
 <?php
 /*
 Template Name: Salespage
 */
 ?>
    <div>
        <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
            <?php the_title(); ?>
            <?php the_content(); ?> 
        <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
    </div>
 </head>
 <body>
 <body topmargin="100">
 <body leftmargin="300">
 <body rightmargin="300">
 <body bottommargin="10">
 </body>
 </html>
```

If my understanding is correct, the values I've used to set margins are html code.

And, if my understanding is correct, there's CSS code I can use instead. This, I think:

```
body {
        margin-top: 100px;
        margin-right: 300px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        margin-left: 300px;
    }
```

If I just switch those excerpts of code, the new version doesn't apply the margins.

What do I need to do to make the CSS code work?

And is one or the other types of code likely to cause fewer issues in different situations, such as displaying on different browsers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your markup is a little outside the realm of validity. :)
The div with the PHP loop should be in the vody and there should only be one body tag. I'd suggest giving your loop div an id then using that as the CSS selector, like this:

```
 <?php
/*
 Template Name: Salespage
 */
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
 <title>Copywriting for Serious Marketers</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="keywords" content="copywriting, sales writing, marketing" />
<meta name="copyright" content="Copyright Richard Clunan. All rights reserved." />
<meta name="description" content="Advice on copywriting and marketing." />
<meta name="revisit-after" content="7 days" />
<style>
#content
 {
    margin: 100px 300px 10px;
 }
</style>

</head>
<body>
<div id="content">
    <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
        <?php the_title(); ?>
        <?php the_content(); ?>
    <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```